# Applying CSS on ready doesn't render properly until window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two JavaScript functions. A function called `Init()`, which checks information rendered on the page, is fired on `$(document).ready()` and, at the end of this function, it calls a function called `Size()` after it is done checking everything.

`Size()` has to be performed each time the browser is resized too, so it can balance out some CSS.

For some reason though, `Size()` doesn't work properly during `Init()` and doesn't actually do what it should until it is called when the browser window is resized.

Are these functions being used properly? Is `Size()` missing something on init?

```
var h = $(window).height(), 
    w = $(window).width(),
    m = 30; // global margin

var fitTop, fitBot;

function fitInit() {
    fitTop = $(".fit-compare-top").length;
    fitBot = $(".fit-compare-bottom").length;

    fitSize();
}

function fitSize() {
    if (w < 1024) {
        $(".fit-compare-item").width(w*0.7);
        if (w > 767) {
            mm = 220;
        }
        else { mm = m }
        $(".fit-compare-tops").width(Math.min(400 + m + 5,(w * 0.7 + m + 5)) * fitTop + mm);
        $(".fit-compare-bottoms").width(Math.min(400 + m + 5,(w * 0.7 + m + 5)) * fitBot + mm);
    }
    else {

        // this where I'm having the problem
        // the height of the follow object remains
        // unchanged until $(window).resize()

        $('.fit-hero-text').height(h-h/5).css({
            "padding-top": h*0.3
        });
        $(".pillars-section").height( (Math.min(1280,w)*0.4)*1.5 );

    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fitInit();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    fitSize();
});
```

I have tried removing the `Size()` from `Init()` and putting it in `$(document).ready()` but that has the same effect.  And I obviously require this function to occur after the page is loaded, because I can't depend on a user to resize their browser.

**UPDATE:** If I removed the `padding-top` CSS rule from `$('.fit-hero-text')` then there is no jump on resize and height is calculated and rendered properly. Why could this be?

Comment: `w` where is it declared?

Comment: @EdenSource -- scroll down, it's there.

Comment: oups sorry, hard day xD

Comment: Ahh, must have scrolled -srry

Comment: So removing the `padding-top` line made it work correctly on doc-ready as well?

Comment: @Ted Correct. And by work correctly, it doesn't have the padding that it should, but at least it doesn't jump around on resize. I have fixed my issue by applying static padding in the CSS, but I still want to know why padding (maybe just applying CSS here) is creating an issue. This problem exists in all browsers.

Comment: Yeah--that's what I meant--working 'almost' correctly. Bizarre issue, there's clearly no obvious issue with the code... maybe for SnG's try setting it as 'padding', with all four values defined in a string

Comment: Can you provide your HTML/CSS?  Hard to determine the exact behavior without it.

Comment: Is this similar to the layout you're after? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjjmQj

Comment: @JoshBurgess I've just solved the issue, see answer below. The HTML and CSS were irrelevant, as the CSS was blank and the HTML is just a div block element.

Comment: @Ted I have figured out that this was because I was using `height()` when I should have been using `innerHeight()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have determined here that the problem resides in using `height()`, when I should actually be using `innerHeight()` here because of the padding that I am also applying in the same line.

[jQuery's `height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) is initially applying the height of the element and ignoring the padding because `height()` does not include padding. [jQuery's `innerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) includes padding and can accept the CSS that's being applied in the same line.

**UPDATE:** I have recently become aware of [imagesloaded.js](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) and this shaves some time off of the window.load time, also removing the opportunity for page elements to be jumping around due to images rendering.

Comment: head slap :D Glad you got it sorted